# How can I remove specific top hits in Safari's address bar?

Tags: safari, auto-complete, browser-history

(Similar to this [How can I remove an autocomplete suggestion from Safari's address bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122428/how-can-i-remove-an-autocomplete-suggestion-from-safaris-address-bar), but those answers do not help)

A site I visit frequently is located at:

```
http://example.com/sub
```

Unfortunately when I begin typing "exa" in the address bar, I get two propositions in top hits:

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/sub
```

with the first being highlighted, and used if I (miss the arrow down key and) hit enter

I have bookmarked and favorited the `http://example.com/sub` site and try to never visit `http://example.com` but never the less it always shows as top site.

I cleared my history of each and every entry to `http://example.com/*` except for `http://example.com/sub`, and redo that step every time I accidently visit the wrong site

And no, I don't want do delete my whole browsing history

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually not possible to remove the root domain from Safari's top hits. I've always had this problem and find it irritating.

> As seen, I've never visited Apple's US website, but only the SG site. However, it still auto completes to it.
>
> [image]

Unfortunately, the problem is that Safari autofills the root domain, before auto completing the sub domain.

So, even if you don't visit `http://example.com`, it would still show up since you visit `/sub`.

Answer (score 5):

After brainstorming for days, I finally managed to find a solution. Putting it here since it may help others. Clearing history on one or all your devices doesn't help. **All you need to do is show your Bookmarks from the bookmarks tab, search for the website you want removed from the top hits (it only shows in top hits because it's in your bookmarks) and delete it from there. That's it, the said top hit will stop appearing on all your iCloud devices.**

What's rather disappointing in all this is even tech savvy people need to bang their head around to find a solution to such a simple problem. In Google Chrome, you can simply select that top result and delete it.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Thank your for your answer, but your post seems to also contain a question. I've removed that part of your post as the *answer* field is purely for answers to the question. Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can add a comment on any post you'd like to comment on. All the best! :)

Comment: If the unwanted top hits are in Safari history, you must delete them from Safari history. Click "Show All History" menu item and search for the unwanted top hits in history and then delete them.

Comment: Yea, turns out it is the same here. Delete a bookmark sharing the same domain fixed the wrong top hit for me.... this is stupid.

Comment: Turns out my top hit to remove is neither in the history, nor the bookmarks

Comment: I can barely contain my rage at typing "news." to open Google News and having foxnews be suggested--that wretched hive of scum and villainy. It's definitely not in my bookmarks, and I've triple checked my history. Whatever amount they're paying Apple, it's not worth it Apple!