# How to remove autocomplete (autofill) entries from Chrome? (Shift+Fn+Delete doesn't work)

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, macos, auto-complete, browser-history

In both Firefox and Chrome (latest versions) when I start typing an address of a website I have visited before, it shows a bunch of autocomplete entries.

If I want to delete a specific entry, in Firefox I can press up or down to select that particular entry, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and it's gone.

Somehow I remember this used to work in Chrome as well, and this is also what I find on various websites. But it doesn't work. At least not in my current version of Chrome (the latest).

How do I remove specific autocomplete entries from Chrome, other than just deleting the entire history altogether? (which I'd rather not do)

In case it's relevant, I'm running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Why would it need Fn to make that work?

Comment: @Tetsujin because that's how it works in Firefox, and that's also how many websites explain how it's supposed to work in Chrome as well. For what it's worth, of course I also tried without Fn, but just using ⇧+Delete doesn't work either.

Comment: The only thing I can think that the Fn does is changes 'backspace' to 'forward delete' [which is usually only necessary if you have a short keyboard]

Comment: On a Macintosh, type enough text to bring up the autofill entry you would like to remove and use the arrow keys to **highlight** the entry you would like to delete, then do fn+shift+delete and the entry will be deleted.

Comment: Why don't you try https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122428/ the suggestions for Safari, on chrome ? Open history, clear the troubling part up, not whole thing, open website data, clear the troubling part up. If it's suggestions, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have a Macbook Pro, not using an external keyboard. So yes, for me, Fn+Delete works like Delete whereas just the Delete key without Fn works like Backspace.

Comment: @Udhy Thanks but I'm doing exactly that. Works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

Comment: @RocketNuts: I tested and it works on my side on Chrome too. I highlight and did it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue and none of these suggestions work.

Comment: @whenitrains Unfortunately not, I switched to a new Macbook Pro last year and didn't have the problem anymore ever since. Never figured out what caused this issue on the previous machine. My Chrome was fully up to date at the time.

Comment: I have trouble with this periodically. Sometime it just does not work.  I have found that reloading the page sometimes fixes it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're seeing within Chrome that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> isn't working, it may be that you have a bookmark for that link. You have to delete the bookmark to remove it from the suggestion list.

Answer (score 1):

When you go into the Settings of Chrome, you will find a Auto-Fill chapter on the left menu bar. Click there and you can manage all your addresses, credit cards and passwords which are used for the autofill function.