# How do I remove an autocomplete suggestion from mobile Safari's address bar?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, auto-complete

(*Similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/122428/72620), but for iOS Safari instead of macOS Safari*)

A site I used to frequently visit keeps appearing as the Top Hit in mobile Safari's autocomplete bar. I would like to remove the URL, as I no longer visit the site and don't wish to be reminded of it.

How do I remove a URL so mobile Safari stops autocompleting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove it from your history.

Search for it in Safari history and then delete them one at a time. Unfortunately clicking "clear", even while looking at search results, clears all history instead of just the search results. There's no way to delete many history entries at the same time.

You can delete an entry at a time from history by swiping leftwards on it, exposing a Delete button on the right of the entry.

Or holding down on the item in history until it previews and a "Delete" button is shown in the context menu.

If you're doing some kind of iCloud sync with your Mac's browser, you will also need to follow the instructions in the question you linked for macOS.

Comment: May want to add that Safari history is accessed with the book icon.